# Java: Why is the ArrayList Parameters of a function effecting a different ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, parameters

I'm relatively new to coding so I apologize if this question is stupid. Why is the Arraylist `numbers` getting affected by what is happening within the function `changeParam` with the parameter of Arraylist for example...

```
public class Test {
static ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++){
         numbers.add(i);
        }
     changeParam(numbers);
     System.out.println(numbers);
    }
 public static void changeParam(ArrayList<Integer> A){
A.clear();
}
}
```

Why when numbers is printed does it come out empty?

Comment: You are passing the `numbers` list as an argument to `changeParam`, which clears the list. `A` and `numbers` refers to the same list when you pass `numbers` to the function.

Comment: Why do you believe `A` is a different list than `numbers`? Do you believe it copied the entire list on the method call? Perhaps because you were told Java is pass-by-value? If so, then be aware that it is the *reference* to the list that is passed by value, not the `ArrayList` *object*.

Comment: This is because your references : ``numbers`` and ``A`` points on the same object address and values of members variables are copied, from ``numbers`` variable to ``A`` parameter. You can test it my calling the function ``System.identityHashCode(Object object)`` on ``numbers`` and ``A``. You will see that they have the same address. This lecture could help you understand more : https://www.journaldev.com/3884/java-is-pass-by-value-and-not-pass-by-reference